# Как удалить строки, содержащие менее трёх слов?

Tags: shell, sed

есть file.txt

как с помощью sed удалить в этом файле строки, содержащие менее трёх слов?

---

должны быть удалены:

```
похудеть быстро
```

должны остаться:

```
похудеть быстро без диет
```

Comment: в строке `1.2` сколько слов (исходя из ваших требований) — два, одно, ноль? если затрудняетесь с определениями, приведите, пожалуйста, образцы строк, которые следует: а) оставить, б) удалить.

Comment: в файле строки с поисковыми фразами, например:

Comment: похудеть быстро

Comment: похудеть быстро без диет

Comment: нужно удалить те строки где меньше двух слов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 sed -ri '/\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+/!d' file.txt
```

Паттерн соответствует строкам, содержащих три слова из не менее, чем одного непробельного символа, разделенных не менее, чем одним пробельным. Команда `!d` удаляет строки, не соответствующие паттерну. Параметр `-r` включает поддержку расширенных регулярных выражений (не стандартный, но в большинстве случаев должен работать).

Answer (score 0):

удаляет строки 2х и меьнше символов 
    `sed -r '/^.{,2}$/d' filename`

Для того чтобы сохранить изменения в файл - нужно поставить опцию -i.

Еще так можно 
    `sed '/^.\{,3\}$/d' filename`

Comment: Спасибо, но мне мне нужно удалить строки в которых менее двух СЛОВ, а у Вас символов

Comment: ой. не внимателен. секунду

Comment: @Вова
sed -r '\S+\W+\S+' filename

Answer (score 0):

как я понял из объяснения в комментариях, требуется удалить строки, не содержащие пробела.

```
$ sed -i '/ /!d' file.txt
```

проверка:

```
$ echo -e '12\n1 2' | sed '/ /!d'
1 2
```

---

дополнение ввиду меняющихся на ходу требований: оказывается, должна быть не одна группа пробелов, а две (т.е., три слова, а не два):

```
$ sed -i '/ [^ ]\+ /!d' file.txt
```

проверка:

```
$ echo -e '12\n1 2\n1 2 3' | sed '/ [^ ]\+ /!d'
1 2 3
```

Comment: если в строке два слова , то пробел присутствует, как тогда удалить такие строки где два слова?

Comment: то есть нужно оставить только те строки в которых 3 слова и более

Comment: так два слова должно быть или три? отредактируйте вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: я написал "включительно" думал меня поймут

Comment: я исправил вопрос и дополнил ответ. проверьте, верно ли я изложил текст вашего вопроса.

Comment: Все верно, всем спасибо, всё работает.

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: Отметил тот которым воспользовался, остальные еще не проверил.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ri '/(\S+\s+){2,}\S+/!d' text.txt
```